# RegEx Find commas before and after 4 digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with the currently cryptic world of regex as I'm a noob to this area:/

I am trying to find and replace commas in a string that are before or after a 4 digit number so

```
,2004,
,2005,
```

The starting one in the string only has a comma after it..

```
2005,
```

What I need to do is replace these with a line break. Any pointers would be very gratefully received. This is being done in JS

Comment: Are there other commas, other characters etc? Is there a reason you can't just replace the commas with a break without looking for 4 numbers ?

Comment: Hi  yes it is all part of a long string that has info on "years" so there are sentences int here with commas.

Comment: I have managed to get to the commas before the digits using: `var res = string.replace(/,(?=\d{4})/g, "<br>");`     Its the ones after I'm struggling with:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
,?(\d{4}),?
```

Guess this way should be better.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/47

```
var re = /,?(\d{4}),?/gi;
var str = 'a,2004,\n,2005,\n\nThe starting one in the string only has a comma after it..\n\n2005,';
var subst = '$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```